# Adding average lines to Tableau bar chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau bar chart which plots a number of measures for one particular row at a time in my data set (using a Quick Filter).

I was wondering if there was an easy way to add a reference line for each measure's average value across the *entire* data set.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to bring in more data and use an alternative filtering method to 'quick filter' (like using a conditional expression in a calculated field). Such as:

if (condition of quickfilter) then
  data
else
  null
end

this way you can view only limited rows of data in your viz, while also bringing in the rest of the data for the average calculation.